# Delete fraction from variable

Tags: php, variables, intervals

I want solution for this problem.

this my code :

```
<?php
$cc = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select count(id) as cc from table"));
$cc = htmlentities($cc['cc']);
$cn = $cc/25;
?>
```

the sum of $cn is 2.04.

I want a solution to delete the fraction part of this variable.

Comment: What do you mean by _interval_?

Comment: Do you mean the fraction `.04`?

Comment: If the total calculation is equal (example 2.14).
I want to change the this total to (2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `floor()` function to remove the fraction after the decimal:

```
$cn = floor($cc/25);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [ceil()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php), [floor()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) or [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) functions.

Ceil() rounds the number to the nearest integer above the current value, whereas floor() rounds it to the nearest integer below the current value.

The round() function, takes two parameters  and allows you to set the number of decimal places to round to. If a number is exactly  between two integers, round() will always round up, but this behaviour can be changed via PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP and PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN constants.